# Magento system.log 'Warning: SimpleXMLElement' - (adminNotification/Model/Feed.php)

Tags: magento-1.7, error

Magento has me stumped again! Within /var/log/system.log I'm seeing the following warnings and I have been unable to track down the cause. Going by the timestamp, it appears as though they're all firing off at the same time so perhaps it's a particular action that sets off the 24 lines of warnings ... any ideas on how to debug?

```
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : AttValue: &quot; or ' expected  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: &lt;html lang=en&gt;  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:            ^  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : attributes construct error  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: &lt;html lang=en&gt;  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:            ^  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 2  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: &lt;html lang=en&gt;  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:            ^  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: &lt;html lang=en&gt;  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:            ^  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : AttValue: &quot; or ' expected  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: &lt;html lang=en&gt;  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:            ^  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : attributes construct error  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: &lt;html lang=en&gt;  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:            ^  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 2  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: &lt;html lang=en&gt;  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:            ^  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: &lt;html lang=en&gt;  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2013-07-17T08:06:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:            ^  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like something is breaking the adminhtml feed module.

The cause could be a third-party module that is retrieving invalid XML.

Check whether your site code contains any class which extends `Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed`.

Once you find it:

1. Try to disable that module (in `app/etc/modules/`).
2. Clean the system.log.
3. See if the error is gone.

Repeat this process for each module.  Once you've determined which module is creating the issue, you can edit it's `config.xml` and comment-out the observer that triggers the notification.

I will also suggest contacting the module's developer and notifying them about the issue.

Comment: Perfect, the solution you suggested worked nicely. I grepped for "AdminNotification" and right away I suspected a specific module when I saw its xml file appear. I set the module to false, reset the cache, logged out/in and the issue went away. I've since emailed the module developer to fix their code. Thanks!

Comment: really helpful +1 for that

Comment: You could also use xdebug to stick a breakpoint on getFeedData method, that way you can see which module is causing it rather than disabling 1 by 1 if you have more than one module using the feed reader.  Helpful answer though +1

Comment: If you dig a bit deeper you can also find the place where the action is called and disable it (in my case it was triggered by an observer that could be easily deactivated by the modules config.xml)