# Magento system.log 'Warning: SimpleXMLElement' - (adminNotification/Model/Feed.php) resulting in error 404 on backend

Tags: magento-1.9, error, backend

Hey guys I got following error:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): in
>   app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php
>   on line 173

which prevents me from literally everything on the backend because everytime I want to edit a product or an order I get an error 404 message (Still can access the backend).

Now I already tried to google it [Magento system.log 'Warning: SimpleXMLElement' - (adminNotification/Model/Feed.php)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5806/magento-system-log-warning-simplexmlelement-adminnotification-model-feed-p()) and people suggest that I had to turn off modules containing `Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed` or "AdminNotification". I literally deleted all the files of the modules which contains these words and deleted the modules from my module folder and I still get this error....

I also loaded a Backup where everything was fine and I STILL get this error... What can I do to fix this or maybe I'm doing it wrong?

The only path/modules I didn't deleted are these:

> includes\src\Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed.php,
>   includes\src\Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Observer.php,
>   includes\src\MSP_Common_Model_Feed.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something is breaking the adminhtml feed module.

The cause could be a third-party module that is retrieving invalid XML.

Check whether your site code contains any class which extends `Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed`.

**Once you find it:**

Try to disable that module (in `app/etc/modules/`).
Clean the system.log.
See if the error is gone.
Repeat this process for each module.

Comment: I already searched for all those files and disabled them but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

This below files are stored in the compilation folder

> includes\src\Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed.php,
>   includes\src\Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Observer.php,
>   includes\src\MSP_Common_Model_Feed.php

So first navigate to `<magento-root>\includes\config.php` and comment both below lines in this `config.php` file.

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Than after clear the cache and again do the compile form the admin.